# getMaximumRange() for Proximity Sensor in Emulator

Tags: android, emulation, sensors, proximitysensor

I try to get a maximum value from getMaximumRange() method for a Proximity sensor in **Emulator** (not in a real phone!). But I get only value 1.0 instead 10. Why?

My code is simple.

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    if (mProximitySensor != null) {
        mProximitySensorTextView.setText(mProximitySensor.getName());
        mProximityMaxTextView.setText("getMaximumRange: ");
        mProximityMaxTextView.append(String.valueOf(mProximitySensor.getMaximumRange()));
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mProximitySensor,
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

    } else {
        Log.e("Sensor", "Not available.");
        finish();
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Some proximity sensors only support a binary near or far measurement.
In this case, the sensor should report its maximum range value in the far state and a lesser value in the near state.

This can be confirmed by using the following USSD `*#*#0588#*#*`

This will Trigger a Proximity Test. Try This on A Real phone or Emulator and Confirm